# How do I export oracle query result without enclosure

Tags: oracle, export-to-csv

I have oracle 12c and trying to export query result to csv or text file but I dont want any enclosure of my data. I have tried SET SQLFORMAT csv which creates csv file but data comes in double quotes then I tried SET SQLFORMAT delimited | but that also comes with double quoted. I also tried SET MARKUP csv on delimeter | quote off it also gave me same result. I dont think MARKUP command works on 12c but it did not give me error. Here is my script:

```
SET SQLFORMAT  delimited | ;
spool 'C:\Temp\MyResults.csv'; 

select 1 AS Col1, 'Data Line 1' AS Col2 from dual UNION select 2 AS Col1, 'Data Line 2' AS Col2 from dual;

spool off;
```

This gives me result:

```
"COL1"|"COL2"
1|"Data Line 1"
2|"Data Line 2"
```

But I want without double quotes on string data.

```
COL1|COL2
1|Data Line 1
2|Data Line 2
```

I would appreciate if someone can give me any poption.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have the following working with Oracle 19 (client and server on Linux):

```
SQL> set markup CSV on quote off
SQL> desc t;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 OBJECT_ID                                          NUMBER
 OBJECT_NAME                                        VARCHAR2(128)

SQL> select * from t where rownum=1;

OBJECT_ID,OBJECT_NAME
16,TS$


SQL> set markup csv on quote on
SQL> select * from t where rownum=1;

"OBJECT_ID","OBJECT_NAME"
16,"TS$"

SQL>
```

Comment: I have 12c and markup with quote off does not work and I dont want quotes on any data element. Thanks for your input.

Comment: What is your exact Oracle version ? In 12.1.0.2 I get `SQL>set sqlformat delimited |
SP2-0158: unknown SET option "sqlformat"
SQL>`

Comment: Oracle 12.1.0.2.0

Comment: Maybe easiest thing to to is to install Oracle Client 19 and to use what I have already answered.

Comment: I can use only sqldeveloper, I can't use oracle client :(

Comment: In SQL Developer there is a GUI feature to export in CSV: maybe it can do the job.  See https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2013/10/defaults-for-exporting-data-in-oracle-sql-developer/

Comment: Yes I can use GUI and it works fine, but I am creating scripts for non-tech people and they can't use GUI.